# I want a radio input type with a label on one line, but I can't seem to figure this out

Tags: html, css, input, radio-button

I want a label and input type with radio in one line

For example

◉ CSS
◉ HTML
◉ Javascript

like this but I can't.

Comment: "*…but I can't*" - why can't you? What problems are you having? Where's your (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code?

Answer (score 0):

By default, HTML will be display them in one line without extra effort, if you don't use anything like a line break `<br/>` or change the default display using CSS.

For example:

```
<input type="radio" id="html" name="language" /> <label for="html">HTML</label>
<input type="radio" id="css" name="language" /> <label for="css">CSS</label>
<input type="radio" id="javascript" name="language" /> <label for="javascript">JavaScript</label>
```